# Библиотека python и пример для прогнозировании комбинаций целых чисел

Tags: python

Всем привет!

Помогите выбрать библиотеку python которая может "спрогнозировать" комбинацию целых чисел, на основе предыдущих значений.  На примере игральных костей d6 - есть пара костей, которые по условии задачи не идеальны и есть результы N бросаний. Вопрос какая библиотека (идеально если будет пример кода) может помочь спрогнозировать результаты N+1 броска игральных костей с вероятностью X. Мне нужно разобраться на примере кода, как решаются подобного рода задачи (конкретно прогнозирования группы целых чисел, на основе прерыдущих групп).

Comment: Советую почитать о машинном обучении, глубоком обучении (`deep learning`), о `time series forecast` и о  LSTM алгоритме. [Пример](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/). Библиотеки: sklearn, keras, tensorflow, pythorch, cafee и т.д.

Comment: Если это именно независимые случайные события, то тут никаких особых библиотек не нужно - просто формулы из теории вероятностей / статистики.

Comment: @MaxU - спасибо за хорошую статью!